# Vectorizing correlation between rows of two arrays in python

Tags: python, vectorization, correlation

I have 2 arrays, for example:

```
import numpy as np
ts1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])
ts2 = np.array([[6,2,7,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[3,2,3,8,5],[2,2,3,1,5],[9,8,7,6,5]])
```

I want to calculate the correlation between each row of **ts1** and the corresponding row of **ts2**, taking into account of two indices (**initial** and **final** element) for each row. These indices are stored in a **pandas DataFrame**, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
indices = pd.DataFrame({'in':[0,1,1,2,0],'fin':[4,3,2,3,3]})
```

I can do that with a simple **for loop**:

```
corrIdx = np.zeros((ts1.shape[0],))
for idx in range(ts1.shape[0]):
    corrMatrix = np.corrcoef(ts1[idx,indices['in'][idx]:indices['fin'][idx]],ts2[idx,indices['in'][idx]:indices['fin'][idx]])
    corrIdx[idx] = corrMatrix[0,1].item()
```

now I want to *vectorize* this for loop with **numpy.vectorize**.

I tried:

```
def calcCorr(idx,ts1,ts2,indices):
    corrMatrix = np.corrcoef(ts1[idx,indices['in'][idx]:indices['fin'][idx]],ts2[idx,indices['in'][idx]:indices['fin'][idx]])
    return corrMatrix[0,1].item()

myFunct = np.vectorize(calcCorr)
idx = np.arange(ts1.shape[0])
corrIdx = myFunct(idx,ts1,ts2,indices)
```

but I obtain the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2163, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2241, in _vectorize_call
    ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2201, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
    outputs = func(*inputs)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in calcCorr
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I get the same error even if I use 2 arrays instead of the dataframe. Any suggestions?

**Update July 10, 2023**

I tried to following suggestions by D.L, but I still have some problems to understand the exact way to correctly define the function to vectorize. The problem is that indices **initial** and **final** are different for each row of **ts1** and **ts2**. So, given:

```
ini = np.array([0,1,1,2,0])
fin = np.array([4,3,2,3,3])
```

I tried:

```
def my_function(a,b,ini,fin):
    result = np.corrcoef(a[ini:fin], b[ini:fin])[0,1]
    return result

vfunc = np.vectorize(my_function, signature='(n),(n),(n),(n)->()')
r = vfunc(ts1,ts2,ini,fin)
```

but I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2163, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2237, in _vectorize_call
    res = self._vectorize_call_with_signature(func, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2277, in _vectorize_call_with_signature
    results = func(*(arg[index] for arg in args))
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in my_function
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

bit confused...

Comment: this would work:  `correlations = np.array([np.corrcoef(ts1[i], ts2[i])[0, 1] for i in range(len(ts1))])`....

Comment: this solution does not take into account the indices initial and final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution finally. The **signature** parameter is actually the key, as suggested by D.L:

```
import numpy as np
ts1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])
ts2 = np.array([[6,2,7,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[3,2,3,8,5],[2,2,3,1,5],[9,8,7,6,5]])
ini = np.array([0,1,1,2,0])
fin = np.array([4,3,2,3,3])

def my_function(a,b,ini,fin):
     result = np.corrcoef(a[ini:fin],b[ini:fin])[0,1]
     return result

vfunc = np.vectorize(my_function,signature='(n),(n),(),()->()')
r = vfunc(ts1,ts2,ini,fin)
```

This way it works. Only note, the speed of execution is the same order of magnitude as **list comprehension** or the **map** function, so, at least in this case, **numpy vectorize** is no more efficient in terms of speed.
Any comments on this?

Comment: The speed, unfortunately, is expected. As the numpy docs say: *"The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."* (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). To get the performance benefits of numpy from an algorithm (i.e. looping in C, and multi-data CPU operations), it has to be translatable to numpy's own operations.

Comment: glad you achieved it & thank you for the credit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **great question** with a good attempt and I managed to get it working.

Basically, you can use `vectorise` but then you have to use a `signature` for anything more complicated than a simple vectorisation.

The vfunc is created with the `signature` parameter set to `(n),(n)->()`, which indicates that the function takes two 1D arrays `(n)` as inputs and returns a scalar value `(())`.

```py
import numpy as np
ts1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])
ts2 = np.array([[6,2,7,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[3,2,3,8,5],[2,2,3,1,5],[9,8,7,6,5]])



def my_function(a:np.ndarray, b:np.ndarray):
    ''' function to get correlation coeffs '''
    result = np.corrcoef(a,b)[0,1] 
    return result


vfunc = np.vectorize(my_function, signature='(n),(n)->()')
r = vfunc(ts1, ts2)


print(r)
```

returns this:

```
[ 0.          1.          0.66226618  0.52128604 -1.        ]
```

This really makes python quite powerful (for many rows) and i will be using this answer myself...

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but it does not take into account the indices initial and final

Comment: @Angelo,  the beauty of this method is that you can just adapt the function to suit your need. So you can select the indices initial and final yourself (in the function).

Comment: your solution would actually be ideal in terms of speed, but I am really a beginner in python, can you show me how it could be written taking into account the initial and final indexes?

Comment: the params `a`, `b` take the arguments `ts1`, `ts2`.  So you can literally do whatever you like.  so for example if you want the first and last index from ts1 it would be `a[0]` and `a[-1]`....   i must say, that you asked the question well enough to convince me that you are above beginner level :)

Comment: I thank you for the consideration, but I am really a beginner in python, I started writing codes with this language just three weeks ago.
However, I have experience programming in other languages, so currently, my difficulty is in using the right syntax in python.

Comment: I tried, but as you can see in my update, the problem persists...

Answer (score -1):

The thing with **np.vectorize** is that it's really designed for simple functions that operate on each element of an array. When you try to use it with a function that does indexing on the input arrays, like your **calcCorr** function, it gets a bit confused. It's trying to apply your function to each individual element of **ts1**, **ts2**, and **indices**, not the whole arrays. That's why you're seeing that **IndexError**.

So, **np.vectorize** might not be the best tool for this job. But there are other ways. One option is to use a list comprehension, like this:

```py
corrIdx = [np.corrcoef(ts1[i, indices['in'][i]:indices['fin'][i]], ts2[i, indices['in'][i]:indices['fin'][i]])[0,1] for i in range(ts1.shape[0])]
```

This should give you the same result as your for loop, but in a more compact form. It's not exactly vectorization, but it's a more Pythonic way to handle this kind of operation.

Comment: Intersting solution. After repeated attempts, I found an alternative way using the map function: corrIdx = np.array(list(map(lambda idx: calcCorr(idx, lts, linCom, sts, smtCom), range(lts.shape[0])))) that has, more or less, the same efficiency in terms of speed.

Comment: this is a good answer and i proposed a similar list comprehension in the comments. However, a vectorised method would surely be quicker...